# How to trigger an action without using signal-slot connection?

Tags: c++, qt

The usual way to trigger a Qt action is to use signal-slot connection. Any other way to do it since my function is not a slot? Such as some direct calls?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can connect signals to non-slot methods using the new `QObject::connect` syntax in Qt 5. It looks like this:

```
connect(action, &QAction::triggered, this, &MyClass::doSomeFunction);
```

In this example, `MyClass::doSomeFunction` does not need to be a slot. [Here is a more in depth explanation](http://qt-project.org/wiki/New_Signal_Slot_Syntax).

If you actually want to trigger a QAction, you can just do so directly, without using signals or slots:

```
action->trigger();
```

Comment: Is it possible to do it by building my own action, reimplementing protected Functions `virtual bool event(QEvent * e)`? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, it's possible but I would personally avoid it.

Answer (score 1):

If connect in main(), it can be like this:

```
void windowAbout(){
   QMessageBox aboutMB(QMessageBox::NoIcon, "About", "This is a weather forcast !");
   aboutMB.setIconPixmap(QPixmap(":/icon.ico"));
   aboutMB.exec();
}
int main(){
   ......
   QObject::connect(aboutAction, &QAction::triggered, &app, &windowAbout);
   ......
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add slot which you will connect with the signal, and you can call your function within it.